# Телеграм бот quiz архитектура

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, aiogram, рекурсия

Пишу телеграм бот (aiogram, SQLite) для квиза. Бот задает вопрос, юзер отвечает, бот проверяет ответ, пишет юзеру верно/неверно и задает следующий. В конце пишет, сколько правильных ответов. Имею табличку в SQLite с вопросами и ответами. Столкнулся на моменте, как дождаться ответа от юзера и задать следующий вопрос? Выглядит так, что делать кучу стейтов не рационально, и не будет возможности развития. Хочется, чтобы сколько я загружу вопросов в базу, столько он и задаст. Думал в сторону рекурсии, но чет никак не могу придумать хендлер и как это реализовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста :)

Добавляю пример моего кода - он задает 2 и 3 вопрос, проверяет 1 и 2 вопрос. На 10 вопросов таких кусков будет 10, они полностью одинаковые)
И ниже 3 функции, которые ему помогают (ходят в базу за данными)

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Quiz.Q2, chat_type = types.ChatType.PRIVATE)
async def show_question(message: types.Message):
    start_num = 1
    correct_answer = get_correct_answer(start_num)
    await message.answer(correct_answer)
    start_num = 2
    if message.text == "Правда":
        if "true" == correct_answer:
            await message.answer("Вы угадали")
    elif message.text == "Ложь":
        if "false" == correct_answer:
            await message.answer("Вы угадали!")
    else:
        await message.answer("Вы ошиблись")

    question_text = send_question(start_num)
    question_img = send_question_img(start_num)
    await message.answer(question_text)
    await dp.bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, question_img)
    await Quiz.Q3.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Quiz.Q3, chat_type = types.ChatType.PRIVATE)
async def show_question(message: types.Message):
    start_num = 2
    correct_answer = get_correct_answer(start_num)
    await message.answer(correct_answer)
    start_num = 3
    if message.text == "Правда":
        if "true" == correct_answer:
            await message.answer("Вы угадали")
    elif message.text == "Ложь":
        if "false" == correct_answer:
            await message.answer("Вы угадали!")
    else:
        await message.answer("Вы ошиблись")

    question_text = send_question(start_num)
    question_img = send_question_img(start_num)
    await message.answer(question_text)
    await dp.bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, question_img)
    await Quiz.Q4.set()
```

Функции:

```
def send_question(id):
    text = db.get_question_info(id)[0][0]
    return text

def send_question_img(id):
    img = db.get_question_info(id)[0][1]
    return img
def get_correct_answer(id):
    answer = db.get_question_answer(id)
    return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаёшь словарь с ключами - пользовательскими ID и значениями - индексами их вопросов.

В хэндлере нового сообщения сравниваешь сообщение пользователя и правильный ответ по индексу. Пишешь - верно/неверно. Увеличиваешь индекс вопроса в словаре. Если индекс больше, чем кол-во вопросов - пишешь, что вопросы кончились

```
users = {} #словарь с индексами вопросов

@dp.message_handler(chat_type = types.ChatType.PRIVATE)
async def message_handler(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    if message.from_user.id not in users: #если пользователя нет в ключах словаря
        users[user_id] = 0 #индекс текущего вопроса у пользователя - 0
        await show_question(user_id) #показываем первый вопрос
        
        return #для того, чтобы если игрок напишет первым сообщением Правда или Ложь,
    #ему не засчитывался ответ - заканчиваем функцию

    question_id = users[user_id] #получаем  индекс (id) вопроса у пользователя
    correct_answer = get_correct_answer(question_id) 

    if message.text == "Правда":
        if "true" == correct_answer:
            await message.answer("Вы угадали")
    elif message.text == "Ложь":
        if "false" == correct_answer:
            await message.answer("Вы угадали!")
    else:
        await message.answer("Вы ошиблись")

    
    
    users[user_id] += 1
    await show_question(user_id) #показываем новый вопрос
    
async def show_question(user_id): #отдельная функция для покзаа вопроса
    question_id = users[user_id]
    await dp.bot.send_message(user_id, send_question(question_id)
    await dp.bot.send_photo(user_id, send_question_img(question_id)

async def show_right_answer(user_id): #отдельная функция для показа правильного ответа
    question_id = users[user_id]
    await dp.bot.send_message(user_id, get_correct_answer(question_id))
```

Что-то вроде того

Comment: Спасибо! Я не очень понял, что ты имеешь под индексом. Здесь вопрос больше в том, как не создавать 10 стейтов == 10 хендлеров если 10 вопросов, а заставить бота дожидаться ответа, задавать следующий вопрос.

Comment: В принципе я неплохо обхожусь без словаря, просто после каждого ответа юзера хожу в базу, получаю правильный ответ по id вопроса и сравниваю его с пользовательским ответом. Но выглядит как миллиард дублирования кода и как шляпа))

Comment: закинул код в вопрос

Comment: Тебе необязательно создавать миллион стейтов - можно обойтись и без них.
Под индексом я имею ввиду id вопроса в базе данных. 
Создай один хендлер для вылавливания сообщения - в нём сравнивай ответ пользователя и get_current_answer(id), где id ты получишь из словаря и увеличь в конце текущий id вопроса пользователя.

Comment: спасибо, кажется, я так пробовал, и не получилось. утро вечера мудренее)) если сможешь накидать пару строк кода для понимания - буду очень благодарен

Comment: обновил свой ответ

Comment: ещё посоветовал бы вам завести словарь или что-то в этом роде для правильных ответов, ожидаемых от игрока и ожидаемых от базы данных, (а то насколько я понимаю ваша проверка не сработает), что-то вроде того:

`right_answers = {"Правда": "true", "Ложь": "false"} #где-нибудь в начале`

И в месте, где вы проверяете ответ:

`correct_answer = get_correct_answer(question_id) 
if correct_answers == right_answers.get(message.text):
    await message.answer("Правильно")
else:
    await message.answer("Неправильно")`

Comment: проверка работает) нет понимания, как это в один хендлер воткнуть

Comment: Один хэндлер, который отлавливает абсолютно все сообщения - (message_handler в моём ответе) - в нём вы получаете id текущего вопроса пользователя из словаря и манипулируете с ним

Comment: пршел пробовать)) спасибо